# cronjob scripts keep running after finishing their job

Tags: bash, process, services, cron, crontab

I have a cronjob that runs every 10 minutes. The script that is running detects sometimes a problem and starts a service (using `/sbin/service XXX start`) that ultimately starts a java process.

In case the scripts gets to start the java service, my initial cronjob script will keep running forever:

```
root      8003  0.0  0.0 106100   212 ?        Ss   00:40   0:00 /bin/bash /root/scripts/cron_script.sh
root     10295  0.0  0.0 106100    40 ?        Ss   Oct25   0:00 /bin/bash /root/scripts/cron_script.sh
root     11135  0.0  0.0 106100   208 ?        Ss   Oct26   0:00 /bin/bash /root/scripts/cron_script.sh
root     22787  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Zs   Oct26   0:00 /bin/bash /root/scripts/cron_script.sh
root     29956  0.0  0.0 106100   208 ?        Ss   Oct25   0:00 /bin/bash /root/scripts/cron_script.sh
```

What I want is to have these scripts gone from the list of running processes (or not to appear at all after the service has been started)

If I kill these scripts the following 2 things happen:

-> My service `java` process is not killed (which is good)

-> I get now in the list of processes the following:

```
root      8003  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Zs   00:40   0:00 [cron_script] <defunct>
root     10295  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Zs   Oct25   0:00 [cron_script] <defunct>
root     11135  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Zs   Oct26   0:00 [cron_script] <defunct>
root     22787  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Zs   Oct26   0:00 [cron_script] <defunct>
root     29956  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Zs   Oct25   0:00 [cron_script] <defunct>
```

So how can I make sure the cron processes are always gone after my service has been (re-)started?

PS: this `cron_script.sh` script is the root of a 5 process call stack until it gets to the `java` service and they all remain running.

Comment: Does the script that starts the java application exit after it has done so?

Comment: why not just ensure the service is started first?